# How to write the class so a several lists will be nested inside it?

Tags: c#, class, member

I want to have a class of 12 months that every month include 6 parts.every parts is a list of float numbers.

I used these classs, but I can't access to list of float numbers:

```
    class months
    {
        parts m1 = new parts();
        parts m2 = new parts();
        parts m3 = new parts();
        parts m4 = new parts();
        parts m5 = new parts();
        parts m6 = new parts();
        parts m7 = new parts();
        parts m8 = new parts();
        parts m9 = new parts();
        parts m10 = new parts();
        parts m11 = new parts();
        parts m12 = new parts();

    }

    class parts
    {
        List<float> p1;
        List<float> p2;
        List<float> p3;
        List<float> p4;
        List<float> p5;
        List<float> p6;
    }

 months aa = new months();
```

I want to add number to float list like this:

```
months aa = new months();

aa.m1.p1.add(11.5);
```

which is better in this case ,struct or class?

Comment: I've changed the title since "nested Lists" are a very concrete thing. A nested List is `List<List<List<int>>>` similarly to a nested (jagged) array `int[][][]`. That's something completely different than you asked for. If you think that the new title sounds odd or you don't like it for some reason, feel free to change it again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields are `private`. You need to make them `public`:

```
class months
{
    public parts m1 = new parts();
    public parts m2 = new parts();
    ...
}

class parts
{
    public List<float> p1;
    public List<float> p2;
    ...
}
```

Also you need to initialize fields of `parts` class.

Comment: how can i initialize fields of parts class? and which is better ,struct or class?